# How do I make serialport work with node-webkit

Tags: node.js, module, serial-port, node-webkit

I need serialport to work with node-webkit. I already have serialport.node but I don't know how to make it work. I always get the same error: "Uncaught error: Cannot find module serialport" and tried it in versions 0.6.3 and 0.5.0.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

node-webkit support all the `nodejs` apis and all its third party modules.
so you can get `serialport` from [serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport) just like other packages of `nodejs`, and follow the instructions the page said. it should work fine after you install `serialport`.

If something is wrong with the version of your `serialport.node`, you can see the [issue](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/963), someone has compiled it successfully. You may want to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build it with `nw-gyp`.